# Python: How to import module that is in the same directory as __main__ to third-party module?

Tags: python, module

I got next structure of package:

```
/
    __init__.py
    shared_lib.py
    project1/
          __init__.py
          main.py
          config.py
    project2/
          __init__.py
          main.py
          config.py
    project3/
          __init__.py
          main.py
          config.py

          ...
```

What I do is start main.py for every project directory.There `shared_lib` being imported.
I want to `config.py` have been imported in `shared_lib` before.

How could it be done? So i need something like

```
import os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__main__.__file__)).config
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand, what you mean. But

If you have 2 folders, with 2 files each you can import them like this.

```
/project
       *Main.py
       *Config.py
       * __init__.py
       /test
            *hello.py
            __init__.py
```

lets say i want to import hello.py and Config.py

```
import Config as conf
import test.hello as hel
```

Comment: i mean import config file that is initially in the same directory as main module. And import it not in main module, but in module that is in another directory. According to your example - import config in `hello.py`

Answer (score 0):

in your config file.

```
import shared_lib as shared
```

I am using eclipe as workspace editor.

If this dosent work, then add the path to environment variables pythonpath

In shared_lib

```
import project1.config as project1
import project2.config as project2
import project3.config as project3
```

Comment: vice versa i need config file to be imported to shared lib